# Problems sampling Double-Ranges in Scala

Tags: scala, range

I want to sample a numeric range (start, end and increment provided). I'm wondering why the last element sometimes exceeds my upper limit?

E.g.

```
(9.474 to 49.474 by 1.0).last>49.474 // gives true
```

This is because the last element is `49.474000000000004`

I know that I could also use `until` to make an exclusive range, but then I "loose" 1 element (the range stops at `48.474000000000004`).

Is there a way to sample a range having the start and end "exactely" set to the provided bounds? (background : The above solution gets me into trouble when e.g. doing interpolation using apache commons math (as extrapolation is not allowed))

What I'm currently doing to prevent this is rounding :

```
def roundToScale(d:Double,scale:Int) = BigDecimal(d).setScale(scale,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toDouble

(9.474 to 49.474 by 1.0).map(roundToScale(_:Double,5))
```

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607402/scala-range-precision-for-float-step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to double arithmetics: `9.474 + 1.0 * 40 = 49.474000000000004`.

You can follow that expression from the source: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/NumericRange.scala#L56

If you want to have something exactly, you should use Int or Long types.

Comment: Or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: My usual approach for not exceeding bounds (and generally in floating arithmetics) is to have some `val epsilon = 1e-8` and then use it appropriately e.g. `(9.474 to 49.474 by 1.0-epsilon)`, or `math.abs(x - y) <= epsilon` (instead of `x==y`) etc...

Answer (score 0):

you should go with `BigDecimal`:

```
(BigDecimal(9.474) to BigDecimal(49.474) by BigDecimal(1.0))
.map(_.toDouble)
```